# Action does not have payload in @ngrx/store

Tags: angular, action, ngrx-store

I have Angular application developed in the Angular 2 and ngrx/store1 or 2 (I do not have package.json or node_moduels). I am trying to set up that application in the Angular 5 and ngrx/store 5.1.0.  As expected, there are something not available in recent version. One crucial this is not working is that Action does not have payload. If I instantiate Action with payload, it returns, "error TS2339: Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'Action';" I followed Action code in ngrx/store library, actually, Action interface defined as following.

```
export interface Action {
    type: string;
}
```

I searched internet a lot about new ngrx/store, however I was not able to find answer, does anyone have some information about it?

Answer (score 3):

actually it's been removed from the new versions of `ngrx/store`. but there are some ways that you can deploy it yourself. check [this github issue](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/31), people have come up with different useful solutions.

that being said, my favourite solution is extending that `Action` interface into a new generic interface like this:

```
export interface NewAction<T> extends Action {
    type: string;
    payload: T;
}
```

and then you can use it like:

```
ExampleAction: NewAction<boolean> = {
    type: 'myType',
    payload: true
};
```

Comment: I really do not know why payload has been removed if developer should redefine like this.... I really do not understand this...

Comment: @AnnaLee if you check the migration docs: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/MIGRATION.md , they say it's been removed because `It was a source of type-safety issues, especially when used with @ngrx/effects` . and it's also said that it was a problem when some action didn't need a payload. but I personally think there was many other work-arounds for these problems; and at least they could implement one of these ways to include payload in actions(like a generic type). so completely removing it didn't seem an smart idea to me too. but I've implemented it and is working for me now

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the migration docs
https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/MIGRATION.md

They note that the payload property on the interface has been removed from `Action` and you need to cast the action to the appropriate type to access the `payload` property

Answer (score -1):

A payload property can be added to your Action.

If your Action has payload:

```
export class ActionWithPayload implements Action {
   readonly type = 'Action With Payload';
   constructor(payload: string) {}
}
```

Comment: this isnt true, not every action needs to declare a payload property

Comment: @jota-toledo I've updated my answer to show only the implementation which is using payload.